# How to define a list of test projects in an Azure DevOps pipeline 'dotnet test' task?

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following task in an Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/tests/*/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
```

pretty simple stuff.

Is there a way I can just *list* the projects I wish to 'test', instead of a regexy thing that looks for all projects in the tests folder?

I tried something like this, but it failed:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 
      - '/tests/Foo1/Foo1.csproj'
      - '/tests/Foo4/Foo4.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just tried it in the web portal and this is the YAML generated:

```
    projects: |
     AAA/AAA.csproj
     BBB/BBB.csproj
```

And it didn't work with opening slash, which is also worth mentioning. Hope that helps.

Comment: And there's no `'  '` single comments on either side of the file names?

Comment: Not in the sample generated. The command `displayName: 'dotnet build'` has them, but projects - do not

Comment: you dont even need to use `` in the display name (unless it got funky characters). and you dont need any quotation after | because its a special character for yaml